# Power Automate and Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium

I am using Power Apps to upload data to google sheets and then UI Flow (Selenium IDE) to input it into a web application. Is there a way I can cycle through the google sheets rows after they have been entered.

Comment: Code trials? Any error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium commands like for each to iterate through rows. Hope this would be helpful.
https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/control-flow